# ES6 destruct and get value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this:

```
const a = {
    b: {
         c: {
             value: 'john'
         },
         d: {
             value: 'doe'
         }
    }
}
```

and i am destructing like this:
`const {c, d} = a.b`

i need to use `c.value` or `d.value` to get the value. so, how to destruct the object to get value without calling the value, or is it even possible?

Comment: Both c and d are undefined the way you destruct them

Comment: You've got to destructure `b` and then the properties within its object `const {b: {c: {value:v_c}, d: {value:v_d}}};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can destructure nested properties directly like this

```js
const a = {
    b: {
        c: {
            value: 'john'
        },
        d: {
            value: 'doe'
        }
    }
}

const {b: {c: {value: c}, d: {value: d}}} = a;

console.log(c, d);
```

It's up to you wether it's easier/more readable to use `c.value` or above line...

Comment: thank you. this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: it worth to add that a default value may help - if c/d are undefined you will get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

you can  destruct nested objects like

```
const {b : {c , d}} = a

{value: 'john'}
{value: 'doe'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like:

```
const {c, d} = a.b
```

because `c` and `d` are properties of `b`, not `a`

Comment: yeah, that was a typo and just fixed. but still, it's not my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the child object:

```
const {b: {c, d}} = a || {};
```